# How to solve 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I have created resource files for FormFlow in my Bot using RView tool and translated the strings using Multilingual App Toolkit (MAT). But whenever LuisDialog class calls the form (under de-DE culture), it throws the exception **'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException'** in BuildForm() method.

Names of Resource files are as following:

[image: Class Hierarchy]

Exception is thrown where BuildForm method returns FormBuilder()

```
[Serializable]
public class StandardInfoForm
{
    private DateTime? _startReportDate;
    private DateTime? _endReportDate;
    private static string _reportApplicationsString;
    private static string _reportEmotionsString;


    public string SearchItem { get; set; } //This property is null in case of reporting
    public string Search { get; set; } //This property is null in case of reporting
    public string Application { get; set; } //This property is null in case of reporting
    public string RequestInputType = "Report";
    public string Format = "img";
    public int? FormatWidth = 1024;
    public Report Category { get; set; }

    [Prompt("What kind of report you would like? {||}")]
    public TextReportType? TextReport { get; set; }

    [Prompt("What kind of report you would like? {||}")]
    public ChartReportType? ChartReport { get; set; }

    [Prompt("What is the application name?")]
    public string ReportApplication { get; set; }

    public string[] ReportApplications;

    [Prompt("Please enter applications names seperated by , or enter * for all possible applications")]
    public string ReportApplicationsString
    {
        get
        {
            return _reportApplicationsString;
        }
        set
        {
            _reportApplicationsString = value;
            ReportApplications = _reportApplicationsString?.Split(',');
        }
    }

    [Prompt("Please enter the emotion name? {||}")]
    public Emotion? ReportEmotion { get; set; }

    public string[] ReportEmotions;

    [Prompt("Please enter emotion names seperated by , or enter * for all possible emotions")]
    public string ReportEmotionsString
    {
        get
        {
            return _reportEmotionsString;
        }
        set
        {
            _reportEmotionsString = value;
            ReportEmotions = _reportEmotionsString?.Split(',');
        }
    }

    [Prompt("What kind of chart you would like? {||}")]
    public Chart? FormatChart { get; set;}

    [Prompt("What is starting date (MM-DD-YYYY) for report?")]
    public string StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _startReportDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
        }
        set
        {
            DateTime date;
            DateTime.TryParse(value, out date);
            _startReportDate = date;
        }
    }

    [Prompt("What is the end date (MM-DD-YYYY) for report?")]
    public string EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _endReportDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
        }
        set
        {
            DateTime date;
            DateTime.TryParse(value, out date);
            _endReportDate = date;
        }
    }

    public string ReportRequest = string.Empty;



    public static IForm<StandardInfoForm> BuildForm()
    {            
        var parser = new Parser();
        return new FormBuilder<StandardInfoForm>()
            .Message("Welcome to reporting information!!")
            .Field(nameof(Category))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<StandardInfoForm>(nameof(TextReport))
                .SetActive(state => state.Category == Report.Standard)
                .SetNext(SetNextStandard))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<StandardInfoForm>(nameof(ChartReport))
                .SetActive(state => state.Category == Report.Chart)
                .SetNext(SetNextChart))
            .Field(nameof(ReportApplication), state => 
                {
                    if (state.Category == Report.Standard)
                    {
                        return state.ReportRequest.Contains("application") || state.ReportRequest.Contains("help");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            .Field(nameof(ReportEmotion), state => 
                {
                    if (state.Category == Report.Standard)
                    {
                        return state.ReportRequest.Contains("emotion");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            .Field(nameof(ReportApplicationsString), state =>
                {
                    if (state.Category == Report.Chart)
                    {
                        return state.ReportRequest.Contains("application") || state.ReportRequest.Contains("keyboard") || state.ReportRequest.Contains("mouse");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }                        
                })
            .Field(nameof(ReportEmotionsString), state =>
                {
                    if (state.Category == Report.Chart)
                    {
                        return state.ReportRequest.Contains("emotion");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            .Field(nameof(FormatChart), state => 
                {
                    if (state.Category == Report.Chart)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            .Field(nameof(StartDate),
            validate: async (state, response) =>
            {
                var value = (string)response;
                var result = new ValidateResult() { IsValid = false, Feedback = $"{value} is an invalid Start date, Make sure it's correct format and a Past date" };
                var startDate = parser.Parse(value)?.Start ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
                if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Today, startDate) >= 0)
                {
                    result.IsValid = true;
                    result.Feedback = null;
                    result.Value = startDate.ToString();
                }
                return result;
            })
            .Field(nameof(EndDate), EndReportDateActive,
            validate: async (state, response) =>
            {
                var value = (string)response;
                var result = new ValidateResult() { IsValid = false, Feedback = $" {value} is an invalid End date, Make sure it's correct format and a Past date" };
                var endDate = parser.Parse(value)?.Start ?? DateTime.MinValue;
                var startDate = state._startReportDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
                if (DateTime.Compare(startDate, endDate) <= 0 && DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Today, endDate) >= 0)
                {
                    result.IsValid = true;
                    result.Feedback = null;
                    result.Value = endDate.ToString();
                }
                return result;
            })                              
            .Confirm("Would you like to confirm.Yes or No")
            .Build();
    }

    private static NextStep SetNextChart(object value, StandardInfoForm state)
    {
        var selection = (ChartReportType)value;
        if (selection == ChartReportType.Application)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "application";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationsString) });
        }
        else if (selection == ChartReportType.Emotion)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "emotion";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportEmotionsString) });
        }
        else if (selection == ChartReportType.Keyboard)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "keyboard";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationsString) });
        }
        else if (selection == ChartReportType.Mouse)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "mouse";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationsString) });
        }
        else if (selection == ChartReportType.Sound)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "sound";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(FormatChart) });
        }
        else
        {
            return new NextStep();
        }
    }

    private static NextStep SetNextStandard(object value, StandardInfoForm state)
    {
        var selection = (TextReportType)value;
        if (selection == TextReportType.Application)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "application";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplication) });
        }
        else if (selection == TextReportType.Feelings)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "emotion";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportEmotion) });
        }
        else if (selection == TextReportType.AppVsEmotion)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "application,emotion";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplication) });
        }
        else if (selection == TextReportType.Help)
        {
            state.ReportRequest = "help";
            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplication) });
        }
        else
        {
            return new NextStep();
        }
    }

    public static ActiveDelegate<StandardInfoForm> EndReportDateActive => (state) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state.StartDate);

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
    bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormBuilderBase`1.Build(Assembly resourceAssembly, String resourceName)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormBuilder`1.Build(Assembly resourceAssembly, String resourceName)
   bei JoeBot.Forms.StandardInfoForm.BuildForm() in D:\PARIS\JoeBot\Forms\StandardInfoForm.cs:Zeile 152.
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormDialog`1..ctor(T state, BuildFormDelegate`1 buildForm, FormOptions options, IEnumerable`1 entities, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   bei JoeBot.LUISDialogClass.<FindStandardInfo>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\PARIS\JoeBot\Dialogs\LUISDialogClass.cs:Zeile 249.
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<DispatchToIntentHandler>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__8.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
   bei JoeBot.RootDialog.<ResumeAfterLUISDialogDialog>d__3.MoveNext() in D:\PARIS\JoeBot\Dialogs\RootDialog.cs:Zeile 122.
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IDialogStack-Forward>d__17`2.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogContext.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IDialogStack-Forward>d__18`2.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   bei JoeBot.RootDialog.<MessageReceivedAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\PARIS\JoeBot\Dialogs\RootDialog.cs:Zeile 79.
```

Comment: Does the error state which resources are missing?  The code that throws the exception is in the SDK here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/FormBuilder.cs#L103

Comment: @EricDahlvang, In exception reason it says, "Missing resources System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]". I have added a stack trace above.

Comment: Some resource is not being found.  You could download the BotBuilder sdk source, remove the nuget packages and add the source project files to your solution, and step through the code causing the error: hopefully helping determine what string is missing.  Here is a blog about debugging the sdk: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/03/debug-bot-builder-source/

Comment: @EricDahlvang, Thanks for answering. It solved my issue. There were three strings missing in translation. It would have  saved a lot of time if SDK's exception message also contained the names of missing fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric described in the comments. The exception was being thrown because of some string translation was missing in resouce file. So in order to find out what strings are missing, i needed to go through the SDK code in **Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow** 
Following code throws exception and you can check the value of **missing.Any()** field to see the names of missing strings.

```
if (name != null)
{
    var rm = new ResourceManager(name, resourceAssembly);
    var rs = rm.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
    _form.Localize(rs.GetEnumerator(), out missing, out extra);
    if (missing.Any())
    {
        throw new MissingManifestResourceException($"Missing resources {missing}");
    }
}
```

This blog describes how to debug SDK
https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/03/debug-bot-builder-source/